# Rotation of a Photon Polarisation with a Unitary

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

As an example of a qubit, one take the polarisation of a photon in which the two states can be taken to be vertical and horizontal polarisation, respectively.

Rotation of a photon polarisation would be performed by a unitary operation $\hat{U}$, would it be possible to show that this unitary operation is a superposition of two different unitaries which rotate the polarisation in the paths $+1$ and $-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equal superposition of a qubit (zero is for example horizontal polarization, one is vertical polarization) can be writen as
$$
|q\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle \pm |1\rangle).
$$
This state can be produced by so-called Hadamard gate described by matrix
$$
H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Application of $H$ on $|0\rangle$ leads to superposition $|q\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$, application $H$ on $|1\rangle$ leads to $|q\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$.

Hadamard gate can be decomposed as $H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X+Z)$

where

$$
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and

$$
Z = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, yes the unitary preparing equal superposition can be composed of two other unitaries. But I would rather call this linear combination than superposition.

Comment: Would you call it a linear combination rather than a superposition because the coherences between the two unitaries do not play a role?

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I am not expert in quantum physics but rather enginer. However, I think that you cannot have a superposition of gates, only states - please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Could the Hadamard gate be written as a linear combination of three unitaries?

Comment: @In fact Pauli matrices X, Z, $Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0  \end{pmatrix}$ and unit 2x2 matrix $I$ form basis of space $\mathbb{C}^{2,2}$. But as you can see coefficients before $I$ and $Y$ are zeros. However, maybe there is another basis where the Hadamard can writen as a combination of three matrices. However, what is a point in writing $H$ as three unitaries?